# used code below to allow Editor access to menus - but change permanent, how do I revert?

Tags: user-roles, editor

I have tried the code below to allow Editors to access menu settings. I then removed it from functions.php but the Editor access is still there so looks like this has made a permanent change!

Ayy ideas how I can roll this back (to remove editor access to Appearance).

Thanks

```
/**
* @var $roleObject WP_Role
*/
$roleObject = get_role( 'editor' );
if (!$roleObject->has_cap( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) {
$roleObject->add_cap( 'edit_theme_options' );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From WordPress Codex:

> Changing the capabilities of a role or user is persistent, meaning the
>   added capability will stay in effect until explicitly revoked.

You might want to do something like:

```
$roleObject = get_role( 'editor' );
if ($roleObject->has_cap( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) {
    $roleObject->remove_cap( 'edit_theme_options' );
}
```